# MySQL Will Not Start - InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally! InnoDB: Starting crash recovery

Tags: mysql, xampp, innodb, mediawiki

I am having some problems with MySQL - the service has stopped and will not restart.

I have an XAMPP stack running MediaWiki which is what uses the MySQL database.  The server itself is a VM running Windows 2003 SP2 with 512MB RAM.

Below is an extract from the mysql_error.log

```
121120 16:11:46 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121120 16:11:46 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121120 16:11:46 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121120 16:11:46 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121120 16:11:46 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121120 16:11:46 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121120 16:11:46 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 28821623
121120 16:11:47  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 28825154
121120 16:11:47  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
121120 16:11:48  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121120 16:11:49 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 28825154
121120 16:11:49 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
121120 16:11:49 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121120 16:11:49 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121120 16:11:49 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
121120 16:11:49 [Note] d:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.25a'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
121120 16:16:41 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121120 16:16:41 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121120 16:16:41 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121120 16:16:41 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121120 16:16:41 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121120 16:16:41 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121120 16:16:41 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
121120 16:16:41  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
121120 16:16:42  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121120 16:16:43 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 28841927
121120 16:16:43 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
121120 16:16:43 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121120 16:16:43 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121120 16:16:43 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
121120 16:16:43 [Note] d:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.25a'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Fixes Attempted:

- Tried starting from services - error 1067 - "The Process Terminated unexpectedly"
- Tried restarting the server itself - no good
- Tried moving the ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 files from directory and restarting server no good
- Tried killing the PID of MySQL from command prompt in case it was still running but it was not running.

If anybody could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

NB> I am also trying to get the RAM of the server increased in case that is the issue.  At the moment of the 512MB only about 90MB is free.

thanks
Dwayne

Comment: http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=195445&sid=9c1f91e85ca713f53544d9029e4c458d

Comment: HI Drew, thanks for the reply. I tried the following from that post but no joy. 1) delete cookies & history 2) stop Apache and remove session info 3) restarted machine.  No other Windows Updates have been applied and the Win Firewall is not enabled.  Thanks